# Instagram & Serverless: get all Instagram post that mentioned/tagged my business account

Tags: api, graph, instagram, serverless

I am wondering if this is simply feasible or FB/Insta does not allow this use case...

I have a community that is ready to share content by posting it on Instagram and tagging media/post/referencing my business account.

Is it possible in my backend while using the Instagram Graph API:

1. to get notified about any post mentioning my business account
2. to retrieve consequently posted content to grant points subsequently on my platform?

I am speaking about a competition where users get points by sharing useful content traced back by my platform

Any informed feedback welcome!

Comment: Have you seen the Mentions api endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/mentions

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have been digging further, the main problem seems that the Insta Graph API expects business account owners to authenticate with - frontend - login, not authenticating from a serverless backend of an Insta business account owner. I did not find any possibility to authenticate by API key/sk by example